# Table of tables indentation multi-line entries

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

Using the titletoc-package and the caption-package, I've changed the appearance of the list of tables (I need the table number to be gone in both the actual caption and in the list of tables):

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty}

\titlecontents{table}
[0pt]                                               % left margin
{\addvspace{.5cm}}%                         % above code (e.g vertical space)
{\contentsmargin{0pt}                      % numbered entry format
    \enspace%
    \large}
{\contentsmargin{0pt}\large}                        % unnumbered entry format
{\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}                 % filler-page format (e.g dots)
[\addvspace{.5pc}]


\begin{document}

    \listoftables

    \newpage

    \section{first section}

    \begin{table}[H]
        \caption{This is a table with a caption}
    \end{table}


    \section{second section}

    \begin{table}[H]

        \caption{a second table with a caption}

    \end{table}

        \begin{table}[H]

        \caption{a third caption that is really very very very very very very very long}

    \end{table}


\end{document}
```

The problem: if a table-title spans more then one line, the indentation of the entry is horrible and I have no clue how to fix it:

[image]

Comment: Change the  numbered entry format to `\contentsmargin{0pt}\large`, ie. remove the spurious space after `\contentsmargin{0pt}` and the `\enskip`.

Comment: @esdd and is there a way to indent the second line?

Comment: You could set the left margin (optional argument) to eg. `1.5em` and add `\hspace{-1.5em}` to the numbered entry format.